How to make a cube which can stretch upwards and compress down?
for a short film I'm making i need a cube which can stretch upwards and compress down. in the image below, the rectangular solid on the left is what it should look like when it compresses down, the cube in the middle is its unchanged (resting position) shape, and the rectangular solid on the right is the shape it should be in when it stretches upwards. i can achieve theses shapes by manually adding subdivisions and resizing the cube(as shown in the second image), but i need to have one object that can be easily changed into each of the three shapes. I've already figured out how make the cube turn into the shapes in the 3rd image using a simple "maintain volume" constraint but that's not quite what I'm going for. I want it to look like the 1st and 2nd image.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

With a Bevel modifier:
Use a simple cube, create 3 shapekeys, one for each shape, give a Bevel and a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object, set the bevel Segments to 3, keyframe the Amount, 0.5 for the basic cube:

0.4 for the vertical one:

0.3 for the flat one:

Without a Bevel modifier:
Create a cube, bevel it, add these horizontal and vertical edge loops, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier:

Create 3 shapekeys (the basis and 2 more shapekeys), edit the second and third shapekey:

Animate the shapekeys:


using shape keys is a good idea, and using a combination of the bevel modifier and the subdivision modifier was also a good idea, but that doesn't give me shapes close enough to the shapes I want. do you have any more suggestions.

In that case don't use the Bevel modifier, only shapekeys as suggested by Blendamed and edit the mesh for each shapekey

That seems to have worked how I want it to. Thanks!

@samuel since this worked for you, could you be so kind and mark that little checkmark located under the votes buttons to the left of the post to we can mark this question as resolved.

You could use two different Shape Keys. One to bring down the upper surface and scale it up on x and y. The other to rise the top and make it thinner.


that look Isn't quite what I'm going for. I want it to look a little more like what i showed in my 1st image, it doesn't have to look exactly like my images but similar.
